# High CPU usage & Lock Contention Rate on Content Delivery servers

Tags: performance

We have a performance problem on our site.

Project infrastructure:

- 2 Azure Regions,
- Each region has 3 CD servers,
- Each CD server is Intel Xenon 2,40 GHz 16 logical processors, 112 GB of RAM.

We have a lot of content on our site, in over 10 different languages.

We are using language fallback very extensively as most our the request we receive is fo language - culture e.g. : pt-pt.

We run on Sitecore 8.2 version.

The problem occurs when we unplug one region.

After running without a problem in one region, when the caches are filled, we do some cache clearing after publish ( basically calling `.Clear()` method on main caches ). After that we observe a high `Contention Rate / sec` value from performance counter (`w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec)`) ,around 1000 / s. After a couple of minutes, sites become unresponsive and we need to plug in the other region.

```
13:54:26 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 1.92
13:55:27 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 18.83
13:56:28 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 14.36
13:57:29 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 1.92
13:58:31 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 298.67
13:59:31 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 928.86
14:00:31 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 934.36
14:01:39 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 916.73
14:02:33 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 805.59
14:03:33 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 1089.46
14:04:34 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 264.80
14:05:36 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 496.15
14:06:37 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 283.79
14:07:38 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 210.54
14:08:38 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 1290.11
14:09:39 INFO  w3wp, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads\Contention Rate / sec : 1597.42
```

During clearing the caches, we also observer a spike in `Garbage Collector` usage (Performance counter `w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC`). It is taking up to 30 % of CPU time.

```
13:54:26 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 25.61
13:55:27 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 23.02
13:56:28 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 6.05
13:57:29 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 14.24
13:58:31 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 15.37
13:59:31 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 19.19
14:00:31 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 12.39
14:01:39 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 21.17
14:02:33 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 16.90
14:03:33 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 5.12
14:04:34 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 18.79
14:05:36 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 8.24
14:06:37 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 22.08
14:07:38 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 28.16
14:08:38 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 0.76
14:09:39 w3wp, .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC : 1.79
```

Can anyone advise on that issue?

Maybe our cache sizes are too big? e.g. for `web[items]` cache has **`24 GB`** of size and it reaches its max size.

Comment: from first impression looks something is wrongly configured in cache settings.But irrespective of that if you have this much of cache getting created then  you can try to same this in Redis or any other CDN cache mechanism. I will also suggest if you can decide cache capturing into chunks and then clear cache one by one one may decease your CPU and memory usage. But apart from this I will Suggest raise a ticket to Sitecore support and Microsoft also to get insights from them.

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni thanks for comment. After further investigation it seems that we have misused the SOLR queries. We have a lot of items in SOLR with a lot of text. When we query the index, we have not reduce number of fields and we receive everytyhing from SOLR where we only used 2 or 3 fields.
I think this should solve our problem.

Comment: awesome happy to hear that